# Ubuntu 14.04 clicking unity-dash bug

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash

After 15-20 days(in average) of working unity-dash stop working as it should. By some reason mouse click goes through of unity-dash window. This bug disappears after restarting of ubuntu, but by some reason I cannot restart system so often, so I would like to know how to fix this issue.

I made [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHeuk5UujnE) of this bug, i hope it will help.